# How to write multiple lines in a file when this multiple lines take as a input from a JTextarea?

Tags: java, swing, file, file-io, jtextarea

I take multiple lines as a input from a JTextarea,
If I write it in a file, then I get that the multiple lines are write in a one line in file

#### Examples:

In JTextArea:

```
I
am
a
student
```

Means: variable.text="I'\n'am'\n'a'\n'student";
When I write the string s in file I get:

```
I am a student
```

But I want that the file will contain the same things as I give as a input means--->

```
I
am
a
student
```

This is the code of writing a file :

```
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
       new OutputStreamWriter(
                  new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF16"));
      int size=1;
      for(Tableclass variable:tablevector)
      {
            out.write(variable.Text); 
            out.newLine();
            size++;

      }
      out.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an `out.write("\n")` after each `variable`'s text is written?

Comment: Do as Vulcan suggests: out.write(variable.Text+"\n");

Comment: I think I can not tell you clearly.
Please see the changes.
I want say I take a input string like as

variable.text="I'\n'am'\n'a'\n'student";

and now I want to write this in file as
I
am
a
student

Comment: How do you view the file, and determine that there are no newlines? In for example Notepad on Windows, just \n is not enough to cause a linebreak, you need \r\n. When in doubt, inspect the file with a hex editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slighty better version would be :

```
    try {
        PrintWriter fstream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt"));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


 for(String word : jTextAreaName.getText().split("\n"))  {    
    fstream.println(word); 
} 
     fstream.flush();
```

Comment: Ahh thank god, had been stuck for hours and finally !

Answer (score 2):

Use out.newLine();

```
   BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( 
   new OutputStreamWriter( 
              new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF16")); 
  int size=1; 
  for(Tableclass variable:tablevector) 
  { 
        out.write(variable.Text); 
        out.newLine();          
        size++; 

  } 
  out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

find this char in your string 
char(10) or char(13)

```
int index = textarea.firstIndexOf(CHAR(10));
```